# “How to fix the 'div panel' in either CSS or JavaScript from closing

Tags: javascript, html, css, liquid

This is regarding a FAQ-page;

I've tested some code, when one *div* is active it doesn't automatically close when I click on another *div*, I do have - and + signs but when a user goes to another `.div` tab the previous one needs to be closed automatically;

I've tried adding a lot of CSS code but I think, that they get overwritten with the JavaScript, I have not made the JavaScript, but tried to debug it and simply my knowledge is really basic compared to HTML and CSS, been troubleshooting this for two days now, thanks in advance!

Below is the code:

```js
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                var i;

                for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                    acc[i].onclick = function () {
                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                        } else {
                            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```css
     button.accordion {
                    background-color: #eee;
                    color: #444;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    padding: 18px;
                    width: 100%;
                    border: none;
                    text-align: left;
                    outline: none;
                    font-size: 17px;
                    transition: 0.4s;
                }

                button.accordion.active,
                button.accordion:hover {
                    background-color: #ccc;
                }

                button.accordion:after {

                    content: '\002B';
                    color: #777;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    float: right;
                    margin-left: 10px;
                }

                button.accordion.active:after {
                    content: "\2212";
                }

                div.panel {
                    padding: 0 18px;
                    background-color: white;
                    max-height: 0;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
                }
```

```html
<div class="page-width">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item medium-up--five-sixths medium-up--push-one-twelfth">
      <div class="section-header text-center">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="rte">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse nobis natus, laboriosam, aperiam alias enim, atque accusantium autem saepe id molestiae animi! Soluta laudantium eaque aspernatur maxime et aut, consequuntur.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mind pasting the code on https://codepen.io or https://jsbin.com/ so I can see what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I'm new to this though, but what I basically want is that when a user is done reading the awnser from the question and simply hasn't clicked the - sign to hide the answer;  and simply goes to another question, so basically the answer is still visible for the user, but it needs to be automatically hidden; I do understand it perfectly but how to code around it? no clue, did what you asked the style is the same:   [codepen](https://codepen.io/Tendiasx112/pen/zQjNVL)

Comment: I think the JavaScript overrides everything.

Comment: BUMP tried to edit the JavaScript but even more weird syntax errors are displaying now...

Comment: I put your code into a jsfiddle. I replaced the mustache values with somy placeholder text. https://jsfiddle.net/goxwypa3/

Answer (score 0):

Seeing what your description code looks like would be helpful - but if it's using `accordion` and `active` classes, this might work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion', () => {
  $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

When `.accordion` is clicked, it removes all `.active` classes from all accordions and then adds it back in on the one you clicked.